# My mongodb insert command functions but the collection is not visible

Tags: mongodb, insert

I am running mongodb 3.2 inside a docker container. I have created a database fine, and am using it, when I run the following commands:

```
> show collections
>
> db.designs.insert({"name": "phil"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> show collections
>
> db.designs.find({}):
{ "_id" : ObjectId("579208b15ee45148bdd30a28"), "name" : "phil" }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: The problem was that show collections was not showing the 'designs' collection even though it did exist and had content. It turned out to be an issue with the version of the MongoDB client I was using.

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out that this is caused by an old mongo client: 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16361